# How to load JSON data in a JavaScript class properties

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON data as follows:

```
[
  
  {
    "position": 0,
    "symbol": "H",
    "name": "Hydrogen",
    "color": "blue"
  },
  {
    "position": 1,
    "symbol": "He",
    "name": "Helium",
    "color": "cyan"
  }

]
```

And I want to load it into a class properties defined as follows:

```
class Element{

    constructor(){

        this.index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 89);
        this.position;
        this.symbol;
        this.name;
        this.color;
        this.loadData();

    }

    loadData(){

        fetch('./json/data.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.position = data[this.index].position;
            this.symbol = data[this.index].symbol;
            this.name = data[this.index].name;
            this.color = data[this.index].color;
        });

    }
}
```

I want that, for example:

```
constructor(){

    this.index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 89);
    this.position; // 0
    this.symbol; // H
    this.name; // Hydrogen
    this.color; // Blue
    this.loadData();

}
```

But what happens is the following:

```
constructor(){

    this.index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 89);
    this.position; // undefined
    this.symbol; // undefined
    this.name; // undefined
    this.color; // undefined
    this.loadData();
    this.exampleMethod();

}

loadData(){

    fetch('./json/data.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.position = data[this.index].position; // 0
        this.symbol = data[this.index].symbol; // H
        this.name = data[this.index].name; // Hydrogen
        this.color = data[this.index].color; // Blue
    });

}

exampleMethod(){

    console.log(this.position); // undefined
    console.log(this.symbol); // undefined
    console.log(this.name); // undefined
    console.log(this.color); // undefined

}
```

What happens is that in the second .then of the loadData() method, the JSON data is loaded well, but it stays there, and what I want is for it to be stored in the attributes of the constructor
How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate? what exactly doesn't work, what did you try, what if you place several logs allong the way?

Comment: I want this.position, this.symbol, this.name and this.color from the constructor to have the data that is loaded of JSON from the loadData() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion

```
class Element{

    constructor(){

        this.index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 89);
        this.position;
        this.symbol;
        this.name;
        this.color;
    }

    loadData(data){

        this.position = data.position;
        this.symbol = data.symbol;
        this.name = data.name;
        this.color = data.color;
    }
}

const res = await fetch('./data.json');
const data = await res.json();

const elements = [];
data.forEach(singleData => {
    const singleElement = new Element();
    singleElement.loadData(singleData);
    elements.push(singleElement)
});

console.log(elements);
```

Comment: It works correctly, but I have to look at how to integrate it in my MVC, because I create the element object from the view class, but for now it works. Thanks!